# Create a UITableView that pushes to a detail tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data

I'm trying to create a table view that has a list of all 50 states. Once one of the cells is clicked on it will move to a new tableView that contains all of the cities within that state. Now I've attempted to create a huge dictionary that just does not work for this amount of data, but I'm thinking that I may have to go the core data route. If so, would anyone be able to point me in the right direction on how to accomplish this?

Comment: [Core Data Tutorial for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started) and [How To Use NSFetchedResultsController](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller). These should get you started.

Comment: You will also need this at some point: [How To Preload and Import Existing Data](http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely suggest CoreData here. You'll have to create a CoreData model that pretty much looks like this:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what did actually! I'm still kinda delving into core data so I wasn't quite sure where and how to add all the lists of states and cities to my core data model, but at least I know I'm headed in the right direction.

Comment: Because you have to fill your model only once, I would check in your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, if the model is empty. If so, add all the states and cities to the model.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sqlite to save the data。or plist

Comment: Could you please explain further?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.